# Keyboard shortcuts at a Windows remote desktop from Mac

Tags: windows, mac, keyboard-shortcuts, remote-desktop

I could not find if this question has already been asked.

In my current project, I log in to a Windows remote desktop server using a browser. My local machine is a Mac. The standard Windows keyboard shortcuts (Ctrl+Z, Ctrl+C, etc...) do not seem to work in the remote. Is there a way to use the remote shortcuts?

I am sure that this is possible within some applications as I have accidentally managed to copy-paste text from one place to another in the remote environment.

Comment: If do the same in opposite direction (VNC into Mac from Windows) Ctrl and Alt key are exchanged, may be it is the same in your case?

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you want to post that as an answer so that I can approve it?

Comment: The issue seems to be that Apple uses command key as a modifier whereas Windows uses ctrl. The remote desktop Windows does not understand that command should be interpreted as control. I wonder if there would be a way to map command->control within a mac?